# Alternative to "I sense a bit of [anthropology]"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, sentence-request

Often I'm looking for a creative way to express something like: "I ***sense a hint*** of *anthropological approach* / *existentialism* etc." I take any suggestions to alter this sentence. Most naturally, I'd go for a food paralel (*I taste a dash/drop* (?) *of anthropological perspective*) but I wasn't able to find a unit of taste. :)

Comment: You're not literally tasting it, so you can be as creative with your descriptions as you like! I mean, people actually describing food will use all kinds of inventive and flowery language. You can *taste a whisper* of something if you like...

Comment: @cactustictacs Right but I think a sentence is more fluent when it goes along a single paralel. So I'm looking for a the most congruent combination. Would you say "tasting a dash" of something sounds natural - even outside the anthropology metaphor?

Comment: @cactustictacs Also, does "sensing a hint" sound OK?

Comment: This looks like an Off Topic (primarily opinion-based) question / request for "writing advice" to me. How about going for the relatively common ***auditory*** metaphor? [*I **detect a note** of cynicism.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22detect+a+note+of+cynicism%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks, I was really looking for any suitable option since as a non-native speaker, I don't really feel what sounds OK.

Comment: I think *detect* is a good neutral one, and you can use it as a metaphor for tasting food or smelling notes in a fragrance if you like. I feel like *taste* (when used in the sense of *detecting*) sounds like an animal sensing prey, and it tends to get used in situations where you want to emphasis that primal nature, like someone *tasting fear*. *Smell* is much more common and civilised-sounding, but that's often used in a negative sense (like you're noticing a sign that something is wrong). Honestly though, this is a complex topic and it probably is more about writing style and what's familiar